# flume.conf location in Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, flume-ng

I installed Cloudera Manager (4.5.0) on a node.

I want to dynamically change the flume agent, but I can not find where is located the file and related flume.conf.

In /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30/etc/flume-ng/conf.empty there is this file, but it is empty and even if I change it will not be read.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -f switch in your flume agent start command to specifically point at a flume.conf file. This is also helpfull/mandatory if you plan to run multiple agents on 1 host

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n agent1 -c ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Right next to it, in my CDH5 distro, is `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/etc/flume-ng/conf.dist/` which contains the template and real config file.

Comment: My ../conf.dist directory is a link to the conf.empty dir. Why?